# retrieving attribute values from all elements in XPATH

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I have an XML File which has a root called "Node", and the rest of the tags are called Variables, Shapes etc.

```
<Node Name="X0578">
    <Dynamo Name="grpConditionDispAlarm" Description="" Class="Group" Category="Shape">
        <ContainedObjects>
            <Shape Name="grpSettings18" Description="" Class="Group" Category="Shape">
                <ContainedObjects>
                    <Shape Name="Text279" Description="" Class="Text" Category="Shape">
                    </Shape>
                </ContainedObjects>
            </Shape>
        </ContainedObjects>
    </Dynamo>
</Node>
```

When I try to parse the XML and get a list of Shapes with their attribute "Name" and their XPATH (which i am getting it from `tree.getpath(shapes)`)

I get a list

```
/Node/Dynamo[1]/ContainedObjects/Shape[1]
/Node/Dynamo[1]/ContainedObjects/Shape[1]/ContainedObjects/Shape
```

My files contain multiple instances of tag called `Dynamo`. I need to get a list of all those Dynamos with each shape that's inside.

```
for dynamo in source_tree.iterfind(".//Dynamo"):
    dynamo_tree = etree.ElementTree(dynamo)
    object_list = dynamo_tree.findall(".//Shape")
    for each_obj in object_list:
        ### Extract Info
        Obj_Name = each_obj.attrib["Name"]
        obj_Path = source_tree.getpath(each_obj)
        ## Uses Pandas DF to save the data
```

Output as below:

| Object Name | XPATH |
| --- | --- |
| grpSettings18 | /Node/Dynamo[1]/ContainedObjects/Shape[1] |
| Text279 | /Node/Dynamo[1]/ContainedObjects/Shape[1]/ContainedObjects/Shape |

Now, technically for us, the XPATH doesn't make much sense. 
But every Shape, Dynamo has an Attribute Called "Name". 
So we want to replace that Dynamo[1], Shape[1], Shape in that XPATH with their respective attribute value "Name".

```
def resolvepath(docroot, shape_path):
    lstPath = shape_path.split('/')
    lstPath.pop(0)
    strxpath = "/"
    resolvepath = "/"

    for elem in lstPath:
        if not elem == 'ContainedObjects':
            strxpath = strxpath + '/' + elem
            resolvepath = resolvepath + '/' + docroot.xpath(strxpath)[0].attrib['Name']
        elif elem == 'ContainedObjects':
            strxpath = strxpath + '/' + 'ContainedObjects'
    return resolvepath
```

I used the above logic to iterate through Objects XPath and create a new string `resolvepath` which then replaces `Dynamo[1]`, `Shape[1]` with their attrib. `Name`.

Output as Below:

| Object Name | XPATH | Node Name | Dynamo Name | Resolved Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| grpSettings18 | /Node/Dynamo[1]/ContainedObjects/Shape[1] | X0579 | grpConditionDispAlarm | //X0579/grpConditionDispAlarm/grpSettings18 |
| Text279 | /Node/Dynamo[1]/ContainedObjects/Shape[1]/ContainedObjects/Shape | X0579 | grpConditionDispAlarm | //X0579/grpConditionDispAlarm/grpSettings18/Text279 |

Now my main concern is that `def resolvepath` takes a lot of time when we consider that depth of shapes may go till 7-8 level.

Comment: You should stop trying to "resolve" the XPath expression. Again, there is not such thing as a "resolved path", you're attacking your issue from the wrong angle. Unfortunately you did not explain what your issue is, so maybe we should concentrate on that first.

Comment: Technically, Resolved Path may not be the correct word. But in this example, it relates that the Shape[1], Dynamo[1] should be renamed / replaced with their attribute "Name". Edited my Question too.

Comment: I know *what* you want, I'd like to know *why* you want it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to resolve the XPATH and get a path according to their Element & Attribute Value ?

You mean something like

```
/*[@Name="RandomNodeName"]/ContainedObjects/*[@Name="RandomName32"]/ContainedObjects/*[@Name="RandomName33"]/ContainedObjects/*[@Name="RandomName34"]
```

?

Comment: Not actually, I want to parse through that xpath `/Node/ContainedObjects/Shape[5]/ContainedObjects/Shape[4]/ContainedObjects/Shape[1]`

And then return a resolved path that will replace the elements like Shape[5] with respective names of those shapes. 

Each Node is different, so they can be accessed through `/*[@Name="RandomNodeName"]`

i am trying to iterate through root.xpath(shape_path) but its not working either, though i might be missing something

Comment: @PratikV There is no such thing as a "resolved path". If you want to have *"the element that has the `@Name` attribute with the value of `'RandomName32'`"*. then `*[@Name="RandomName32"]` is the way to express that. `'RandomName32'` is not the element's name. The name of the element is `shape` or `node`, that it has an attribute called `@Name` is of no significance whatsoever.

Comment: Gotcha. I was confused between Element & Node. Is it possible to iterate through that XPATH then?

Comment: @PratikV What do you mean by *"iterate through the XPath"*? If the XPath selects a bunch of nodes, then you can iterate through those, but I guess that's not what you're asking.